# div first table make a color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have below Div tag, having 3 tables in it. How change back ground color for 1st table?

```
<div id="WebPartWPQ2" width="100%" HasPers="false" allowExport="false">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add a "-" between background and color.

```
$('div#WebPartWPQ2 table:first').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Comment: not quite: you can either use  .css('background-color','red');  or .css(backgroundColor, 'red');

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div#WebPartWPQ2 table:first').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
```

Comment: mentioning the tags prevents the use of getElementById, thus is a bit more expensive in performance than simply #WebPartWPQ2 .

Comment: @pixeline Nice, I didn't know that... in my head I thought more information was better... I thought selectors were parsed right-to-left and it wouldn't have made difference.  Anyhow, shame on the CSS parser but good to know! ;p

Comment: my pleasure. Read this for more tips on jquery optimisation http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This uses a valid `querySelectorAll` selector, then adds a class, which is usually more desirable than setting individual styles.

```
$('#WebPartWPQ2 > table:first-child').addClass( 'someClass' );
```

Another way to do it with a valid `qsa` selector would be to select all tables, and use the [`slice()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to get the first.

```
$('#WebPartWPQ2 > table').slice(0,1).addClass( 'someClass' );
```

Selectors like `:first` are not recognized by `qsa`, and in my opinion it is better to avoid them.

The selectors used above are:

- the [`id-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `'#WebPartWPQ2`
- the [`child-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)  `>`
- the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) `table`
- the [`first-child-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) `:first-child`

Comment: Good call: separate content(html) from style(css) and behaviour (js).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector to find the first table in the `div`. Then just apply your color to it:

```
jQuery("table:first", "#WebPartWPQ2").css('backgroundColor', myColor);
```